# A multitrait-multimethod matrix and data set

Tags: psychometrics, structural-equation-modeling

I am working my way through Multitrait-Multimethod Matrix in a psychometrics class.  We're only required to be able to analyze them but I'd really like to be able to construct them.  I think I am able to do that (basically it's a rearangement of the correlation matrix with coefficient alpha for the diagonals).  I am pretty sure I got it but want a **data set** and a **finished MTMM example** (something that looks like the format below):[image]

That way i can work my way through and make sure my final product looks like it's supposed to.  I've attempted for a number of hours to find something but am frustrated and hoping someone has such a resource.  I use R so i don't care what format the data set is in.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this help? http://comisef.wikidot.com/tutorial:correlation or here: http://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/StatPages/More_Stuff/Gener_Correl_Numbers.html

Comment: Cool display, Tyler. Can you post R code that you used to create this?

Comment: @StasK This was not created in R (though I'm sure could be) I posted it more to look at the set up of the MTMM (what goes where).

Comment: You may want to also ask @chl what source he pulled the above picture from ([in this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9944/1036) on the site). You never know maybe the authors made have stated how they made the picture. You could do it in a spreadsheet program such as excel as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked on this some the other day when you posted your [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9628499/604456) to stack overflow. What I will provide won't be a finished solution, but hopefully it will give you enough ideas to finish the presentation on your own.

[image]

This is what I could produce in SPSS, I have posted some code [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3385251/mtmm_in_ggplot2.R) using the same logic in R with ggplot2, but I'm not as familiar with ggplot2 as I am with SPSS so it is a bit off from producing something as close to floor ready as I can with SPSS.

As I said in the comment to your SO post, in a grammar of graphics style you can refer to the methods as *panels* (facets or small-multiples are other synonyms) and the traits as defining location along the X and Y axis. Even though they are nominal categories (so there order is arbitrary) we can still treat them the say way we do continuous variables in a scatterplot. That is, we can assign observations X and Y locations in a cartesian coordinate system defined by the categories.

So the shape your data needs to be in (in either SPSS or R) to produce this graphic is as follows (this is a read data statement for SPSS, but this should be readily transferable to a variety of languages).

```
data list free / Method_X Method_Y Traits_X Traits_Y (4A1) Corr (F3.2).
begin data
1 1 a a .89
1 1 a b .51
1 1 b b .89
1 1 a c .38
1 1 b c .37
1 1 c c .76
1 2 a a .57
1 2 b a .22
1 2 c a .09
1 2 a b .22
1 2 b b .57
1 2 c b .10
1 2 a c .11
1 2 b c .11
1 2 c c .46
2 2 a a .93
2 2 a b .68
2 2 b b .94
2 2 a c .59
2 2 b c .58
2 2 c c .84
1 3 a a .56
1 3 b a .22
1 3 c a .11
1 3 a b .23
1 3 b b .58
1 3 c b .12
1 3 a c .11
1 3 b c .11
1 3 c c .45
2 3 a a .67
2 3 b a .42
2 3 c a .33
2 3 a b .43
2 3 b b .66
2 3 c b .34
2 3 a c .34
2 3 b c .32
2 3 c c .58
3 3 a a .94
3 3 a b .67
3 3 b b .92
3 3 a c .58
3 3 b c .60 
3 3 c c .85
end data.
```

Now, for my graph I want to define one more variable (the variable used to color the blocks) and add some meta-data which propagates to the graph in SPSS.

```
value labels Method_X Method_Y
1 'Method 1'
2 'Method 2'
3 'Method 3'.

compute type = 0.
if method_x = method_y and traits_x = traits_y type = 1.
if method_x = method_y and traits_x <> traits_y type = 2.
if method_x <> method_y and traits_x = traits_y type = 3.
if method_x <> method_y and traits_x <> traits_y type = 4.

value labels type
1 'reliability'
2 'validity'
3 'heterotrait-monomethod'
4 'heterotrait-heteromethod'.
```

Now the fun part, generating the graph. SPSS's graphics language, GPL, is not as intuitive as what Hadley has written for ggplot2, but I can help break it down some. Basically everything is superfluous for our discussion here except the `GUIDE` statements and below (so just focus on those for now).

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Traits_Y Traits_X Method_Y Method_X corr type
    MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Traits_X=col(source(s), name("Traits_X"), unit.category())
  DATA: Traits_Y=col(source(s), name("Traits_Y"), unit.category())
  DATA: Method_Y=col(source(s), name("Method_Y"), unit.category())
  DATA: Method_X=col(source(s), name("Method_X"), unit.category())
  DATA: type=col(source(s), name("type"), unit.category())
  DATA: corr=col(source(s), name("corr"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), null())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), opposite())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(4))
  SCALE: cat(dim(2), reverse())
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), map(("1", color.black), ("2", color.darkgrey), ("3", color.lightgrey), ("4",color.white)))
  ELEMENT: polygon(position(Traits_X*Traits_Y*Method_X*Method_Y), color.interior(type), label(corr))
END GPL.
```

The element statement in essence specifies where things go in the plot (and what gets assigned what colors and labels. In this example the variable `Traits_X` gets *mapped* to the x axis (`dim(1)`), `Traits_Y` goes to the y axis `dim(2)`, `Method_X` gets mapped to the panels going horizontally `dim(3)`, and `Method_Y` gets mapped to the panels running vertically `dim(4)`. Everything else just has to do with aesthetics in the plot (what gets what color and what label goes where).

Not all chart elements are directly exposed in SPSS syntax (you often have to [hack the chart template](http://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/hacking-the-default-spss-chart-template/) to have certain aspects produced in a particular manner), but post-hoc editing gets you along ways in this instance. The extent I am able to reproduce the above chart (without going to great extremes) is inserted at the beginning of the question.

Two things I cannot do in SPSS (without doing hacky things with inserting text boxes on my own) are superscripts/subscripts and having label text in different colors (the labels are there, just black). These are things I would just print the graph to PDF and edit some more in Inkscape or Illustrator. I know you can do subscripts and superscripts in R labels, but one thing to note is this would break the grammar I have previously provided, as the categorical Y axis change between panels.

I could do the dashed boxes fairly easily in SPSS's editor (as well as the other text), but the arrow I could not. I know you wanted a solution in R, and I'm sure most of this logic can be ported to R code (using whatever packages you want).

---

A note, in some of the comments it appears Tyler and me were confused about what MTMM is (at least I was). [This page by David Kenny](http://davidakenny.net/cm/mtmm.htm) goes into more detail on what the method is and how to estimate such models.

Comment: thank you.  I will try this later when I get home.  Just one quick note this was not the same question as on SO.  On SO I asked how to do it.  I never really got a response there but after asking friends I think I figured it out.  The question here was for a data set and a finished product to test what I think will work.  I avoid cross posting unless I explicitly state I've done so.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what the differences between the questions are (are you saying you want someone to do an exploratory factor analysis for you?). If you figured it out yourself though you should post an answer (either here, at SO or both).

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it in R(that's what the question on SO was about) but I can't be sure because I don't have a data set and know worked example (what this question is about) to check the method I'm using in R.  Once I confirm that the method works (Using the information garnered from this question) I will go back to SO and post the R method for constructing a MTMM (answer my own question).Essentially this question here was "I think I got a way to do this but I need a known data set and outcome to make sure the method produces the MTMM and not a random matrix.

Comment: The MTMM is just an exploratory factor analysis with the elements in the **estimated** correlation matrix arranged in a particular order. You didn't re-write a program to conduct EFA did you? So I thought all you needed help with was producing the plot. Any observed correlation matrix and the "known" estimated correlation matrix from an EFA should do (unfortunately it appears the correlation matrix I used was just made up by Campbell in the original article).

Comment: I was definitely unclear in my first post. I actually don't really care about pretty plotting. The pic was to provide the format and it mis-communicated my intention. I am in an applied psychometrics class but beyond just interpreting MTMM I wanted to know how to create it and the theory behind it.  In creating one I came to the conclusion that an MTMM is just a correlation matrix with items summed(or mean) and grouped by method.The diagonal is replaced with cronbach's alpha(usually) and the upper tri. is left blank. I was making MTMM too complicated.  I'll post what I have on SO for feedback.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused. I assumed the MTMM matrices provided were the reproduced correlations based on an exploratory factor analysis (with a fixed number of eigen-values extracted to attempt to reproduce that matrix, perhaps based on the number of traits would make the most sense). I could very well be wrong though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2747/discussion-between-andy-w-and-tyler-rinker)

Comment: (+1) The R code looks promising! I will look further into it when I have time.

Answer (score 9):

I built on @Andy W's R-code and hope my changes are useful to someone else.

I mainly changed it, so that it

- obeys the new syntax (no more opts) in ggplot2, so no more warnings
- adds the correlations as text
- now correlation text size reflects its effect size
- colour scheme shows the type of correlation (hetero/mono-trait/method).
- put the legend in the empty upper right triangle

The function also contains my way for creating the data in the right format from a dataframe or correlation table. This depends on having your trait and method encoded in the variable name and you'd probably want to extract CFA loadings for a more solid look at the matter. In my case I first wanted to eyeball the correlations with a bit more visual structure. If you have your correlations/loadings in long format already it should be easy to adapt the function or to cast the long to wide.

#### Edit:

I put this in a package on Github. You can get it using `devtools::install_github("rubenarslan/formr")`, the  function is then `formr:mtmm`.

[image: MTMM]

```
## function for rendering a multi trait multi method matrix
mtmm = function (
    variables, # data frame of variables that are supposed to be correlated
    reliabilities = NULL, # reliabilties: column 1: scale, column 2: rel. coefficient
    split_regex = "\\.", # regular expression to separate construct and method from the variable name. the first two matched groups are chosen
    cors = NULL
) {
    library(stringr); library(Hmisc);   library(reshape2); library(ggplot2)

    if(is.null(cors)) 
        cors = cor(variables, use="pairwise.complete.obs") # select variables

    var.names = colnames(cors)

    corm = melt(cors)
    corm = corm[ corm[,'Var1']!=corm[,'Var2'] , ] # substitute the 1s with the scale reliabilities here
    if(!is.null(reliabilities)) {
        rel = reliabilities
        names(rel) = c('Var1','value')
        rel$Var2 = rel$Var1
        rel = rel[which(rel$Var1 %in% var.names), c('Var1','Var2','value')]
        corm = rbind(corm,rel)
    }

    if(any(is.na(str_split_fixed(corm$Var1,split_regex,n = 2)))) 
 {
  print(unique(str_split_fixed(corm$Var1,split_regex,n = 2)))
  stop ("regex broken")
 }
 corm[, c('trait_X','method_X')] = str_split_fixed(corm$Var1,split_regex,n = 2)  # regex matching our column naming schema to extract trait and method
    corm[, c('trait_Y','method_Y')] = str_split_fixed(corm$Var2,split_regex,n = 2)

    corm[,c('var1.s','var2.s')] <- t(apply(corm[,c('Var1','Var2')], 1, sort)) # sort pairs to find dupes
    corm[which(
        corm[ ,'trait_X']==corm[,'trait_Y'] 
        & corm[,'method_X']!=corm[,'method_Y']),'type'] = 'monotrait-heteromethod (validity)'
    corm[which(
        corm[ ,'trait_X']!=corm[,'trait_Y'] 
        & corm[,'method_X']==corm[,'method_Y']), 'type'] = 'heterotrait-monomethod'
    corm[which(
        corm[ ,'trait_X']!=corm[,'trait_Y'] 
        & corm[,'method_X']!=corm[,'method_Y']), 'type'] = 'heterotrait-heteromethod'
    corm[which( 
        corm[, 'trait_X']==corm[,'trait_Y'] 
        & corm[,'method_X']==corm[,'method_Y']), 'type'] = 'monotrait-monomethod (reliability)'

    corm$trait_X = factor(corm$trait_X)
    corm$trait_Y = factor(corm$trait_Y,levels=rev(levels(corm$trait_X)))
 corm$method_X = factor(corm$method_X)
 corm$method_Y = factor(corm$method_Y,levels=levels(corm$method_X))
    corm = corm[order(corm$method_X,corm$trait_X),]
    corm = corm[!duplicated(corm[,c('var1.s','var2.s')]), ] # remove dupe pairs

    #building ggplot
    mtmm_plot <- ggplot(data= corm) + # the melted correlation matrix
        geom_tile(aes(x = trait_X, y = trait_Y, fill = type)) + 
        geom_text(aes(x = trait_X, y = trait_Y, label = str_replace(round(value,2),"0\\.", ".") ,size=log(value^2))) + # the correlation text
        facet_grid(method_Y ~ method_X) + 
        ylab("")+ xlab("")+
        theme_bw(base_size = 18) + 
        theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA), 
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                    axis.line = element_line(), 
                    strip.background = element_blank(),
                    panel.grid = element_blank(),
                    legend.position = c(1,1),
                    legend.justification = c(1, 1)
        ) + 
        scale_fill_brewer('Type') +
        scale_size("Absolute size",guide=F) +
        scale_colour_gradient(guide=F)

    mtmm_plot
}

data.mtmm = data.frame(
    'Ach.self report' = rnorm(200),'Pow.self report'= rnorm(200),'Aff.self report'= rnorm(200),
    'Ach.peer report' = rnorm(200),'Pow.peer report'= rnorm(200),'Aff.peer report'= rnorm(200),
    'Ach.diary' = rnorm(200),'Pow.diary'= rnorm(200),'Aff.diary'= rnorm(200))
reliabilities = data.frame(scale = names(data.mtmm), rel = runif(length(names(data.mtmm))))
mtmm(data.mtmm, reliabilities = reliabilities)
```

Comment: This code looks very interesting.  Would it be possible for you to post your "imput" dataset somewhere so I could play with it?  I can't quite visualize what you are doing with all of your which/melt statements.

Comment: @Twitch_City I added some sample data and put the code into a function. You can specify a custom regular expression to control how variables are split into method and trait. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like I forgot to link to the [original resource](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/mtmmmat.php) I used to construct this picture, that was used as an illustration for an old course (I tend to prefer B&W pictures :-). I know nothing about the data, and that was not of primary interest at the time I used it (it was done with Omnigraffle for Mac).

If the question is about how to reach such figures, you can try to generate correlation matrices on your own, using the excellent [psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html) package. (Be sure to check William Revelle's [website](http://personality-project.org/r/book/).) However, for well-established data you could probably refer to

> Brown, TA (2006). [*Confirmatory Factor Analysis for Applied
>   Research*](http://people.bu.edu/tabrown/cfabook.html). The Guilford Press.

See data for [Table 6.1](http://people.bu.edu/tabrown/Ch6/tab6.1.dat). Some context (pp. 214-216):

> In this illustration, the researcher whishes to examine the construct
>   validity of the DSM-IV Cluster A personality disorders, which are
>   enduring patterns of symptoms characterized by odd or eccentric
>   behaviors (American Psychiatric Association, 1994). Cluster A is
>   comprised of three personality disorder constructs: (1) paranoid (an
>   enduring pattern of distrust and suspicion such that others' motives
>   are interpreted as malevolent); (2) schizoid (an enduring pattern of
>   detachment from social relationships and restricted range of emotional
>   expression); and (3) schizotypal (an enduring pattern of acute
>   discomfort in social relationships, cognitive and perceptual
>   distortions, and behavioral eccentricities). In a sample of 500
>   patients, each of these three traits is measured by three assessment
>   methods: (1) a self-report inventory of personality disorders; (2)
>   dimensional ratings from a structured clinical interview of
>   personality disorders; and (3) observational ratings made by
>   paraprofessional staff. Thus, Table 6.1 is a 3 (T) x 3 (M) matrix,
>   arranged such that the correlations among the different traits
>   (personality disorders: paranoid, schizotypal, schizoid) are nested
>   within each method (assessment type: inventory, clinical interview,
>   observer ratings).

The result should look like this:

[image]

If you are using R, you might be interested in looking into the `mtmm()` function from the [psy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psy/index.html) package (which can be used to assess convergent and discriminant validity within a single measurement instrument as well), as already mentioned in earlier replies of mine: [How to compute correlation between/within groups of variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9944/930), [Which package to use for convergent and discriminant validity in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20232/930)

Comment: Well on behalf of your students (and everyone else) I thank you for not using the original colors in the picture!